# HttpsURLConnection server_name corrupted (?) over 3g

Tags: android, ssl, 3g, sni

As per Google recommendation, I am using HttpsURLConnection for my api-level 15 project.

My test case is very simple :

```
URL url = new URL(STATS);
HttpsURLConnection we = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(we.getInputStream());
```

When I connect to my server over WiFi, everything works fine.

When I connect to my server over 3g, I am getting an error in my Apache logs :

```
Hostname 202.139.83.152 provided via SNI and hostname myserver.com provided via HTTP are different
```

Now the 202.139.83.152 address is the proxy address of my mobile providers APN.

I have dumped out the 'Client Hello' packet of both requests and the Handshake Protocol/Extension:server_name field contains the target hostname (myserver.com) for the wifi request but the APN proxy address for the 3g request.

Is this :

- Something I have coded incorrectly
- Something I have configured incorrectly on my phone (Samsung Galaxy S3)
- Something I have configured incorrectly on my server
- Something evil my mobile provider is doing
- A bug in the Android libraries

My server is using a dedicated ip address for this vhost.

I can successfully make a request over 3g using a simple subclass of DefaultHttpClient but as my min API level is 15, I was hoping to go down the 'preferred' path.

Any suggestions would be very greatfully received.  I've spent way too much time trying to get this basic thing working.

My colleague who is handling the iPhone development for this project shakes his head because his code 'just works out of the box'.

Comment: You should check if the proxy is really necessary for using the APN. See your phone's APN config.

Comment: Thanks Robert.  Wow.  I was using the 'default' APN that got set up when I inserted the SIM for the first time (I presume).  All other internet access over 3g was working just fine.  I found an alternative APN that had no proxy setting and my code now works !!  However, what does this mean in terms of potential users of my app?  If a carrier _requires_ (?) a proxy, what then?  Is there any way I can either bypass or compensate for the proxy in my code?

Comment: In Europe providers with pre-configured proxies are rare. Even if they are using proxies the proxy should usually use HTTPS-pass-through which does not alter anything. Therefore I assume that this situation should only occur very seldom.

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that this is a [known issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35050).

I have found a workaround although I'm not sure how robust it is.  What works for me so far is to disable the Proxy when making the connection :

```
HttpsURLConnection http = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection(Proxy.NO_PROXY);
```

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you, @Horrendo, find this to be a stable workaround?

Comment: @BobbyJ, I can only test it out with my current mobile provider but with them at least it works fine.  Not ideal but I can't afford to wait for Google to fix the problem and for the fix to be 'universally' available.

Comment: Thanks. I've been using it with several mobile providers in Sweden and WiFi networks with different setups. I've had no problems with the connection.

Comment: Thank you for fix! Its weird that issue is still persist.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my server side workaround for Apache (working for the last year on Apache2 - Apache/2.2.14).

Recompiled Apache/mod_ssl.so after having changed ssl_engine_kernel.c by removing the "return HTTP_BAD_REQUEST;" for the strcmp(host, servername) check :

```
if (strcmp(host, servername)) { 
        ap_log_error(APLOG_MARK, APLOG_ERR, 0, r->server, 
                "Hostname %s provided via SNI and hostname %s provided" 
                    " via HTTP are different", servername, host); 
        //return HTTP_BAD_REQUEST; // REMOVE THIS LINE
```

You will still get the error log message but not the error 400 response code.